# Alternative to using multiple WITH subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm practicing data analysis through the Cyclistic case study from the Google Data Analytics Professional Certificate. In the middle of my analysis, I developed this query to get bike-sharing data by season.

What is a less verbal / smarter way to do it, since the only thing that changes from subquery to subquery is the name of the season and the month interval?

```
WITH summer AS (
    SELECT
        'summer' AS season,
        avg(ride_duration) AS avg_ride_duration,
        max(ride_duration) AS max_ride_duration,
        count(ride_id) AS ride_count,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_of_week) AS mode_day_of_week
    FROM trip_data_total
    WHERE
        extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 06 AND 08
),
autumn AS (
    SELECT
        'autumn' AS season,
        avg(ride_duration) AS avg_ride_duration,
        max(ride_duration) AS max_ride_duration,
        count(ride_id) AS ride_count,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_of_week) AS mode_day_of_week
    FROM trip_data_total
    WHERE
        extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 09 AND 11
),
winter AS (
    SELECT
        'winter' AS season,
        avg(ride_duration) AS avg_ride_duration,
        max(ride_duration) AS max_ride_duration,
        count(ride_id) AS ride_count,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_of_week) AS mode_day_of_week
    FROM trip_data_total
    WHERE
        extract(month FROM started_at) IN (12,01,02)
),
spring AS (
    SELECT
        'spring' AS season,
        avg(ride_duration) AS avg_ride_duration,
        max(ride_duration) AS max_ride_duration,
        count(ride_id) AS ride_count,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_of_week) AS mode_day_of_week
    FROM trip_data_total
    WHERE
        extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 03 AND 05
)
SELECT * FROM summer
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM autumn
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM winter
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM spring
ORDER BY ride_count DESC
```

Comment: Yes, just use a CASE statement to calculate the season and GROUP BY it - then you only need a single SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case statement` instead and you group by that as well to keep the groups separated:

```
 SELECT
        case when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 06 AND 08 then 'summer' 
             when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 09 AND 11 then 'fall'
             when extract(month FROM started_at) IN (12,01,02) then 'winter'
             when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 03 AND 05 then 'spring' 
        end AS season,
        avg(ride_duration) AS avg_ride_duration,
        max(ride_duration) AS max_ride_duration,
        count(ride_id) AS ride_count,
        mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY day_of_week) AS mode_day_of_week
FROM trip_data_total
group by case when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 06 AND 08 then 'summer' 
             when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 09 AND 11 then 'fall'
             when extract(month FROM started_at) IN (12,01,02) then 'winter'
             when extract(month FROM started_at) BETWEEN 03 AND 05 then 'spring' 
        end
ORDER BY count(ride_id) DESC
```

Comment: It worked! I noticed that you removed the alias from the ORDER BY clause, though. Is it not a good practice? It hasn't returned an error for me

Comment: @DavidEler no difference, it's just some databases won't recognize alias in the order by clause